# Average time of a student enrolling in school

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

[image: Data given]

Estimate the average time-length that a student is enrolled at the university (including students who graduate and those transfer or drop out)

**My thought:** I computed the percentage of new student, classified as either first-year or transfer, in each of year 1-5. I also computed the number of students who dropped out in each year (but I could not determine how long they stay, which is the key point). Anyway, I think we could use Little's Law ($L_i = \lambda_i W_i$), but I am stuck on getting $\lambda$ and $W$ (is $W_i$ equal to the total enrollment in year i? Similarly, is $\lambda_i$ equal to the total number of new students in year i?).

**My question:** I would sincerely appreciate if someone could give some thought on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are correct that this is supposed to be an exercise using and
understanding *Little's Law.*

Average 'Enrollment', which I would view as $L$ (number in system) seems fairly stable *around* 17,000. So it seems realistic to assume the system is at
steady state. (You can find the mean, instead of my rough guess of 17,000.)

I would view 'New Students' as providing information on $\lambda$ (rate of entry).

From $L$ and $\lambda,$ I guess you are supposed to estimate $W$ (average time in system).

If $W$ is to be average *years* in the system, then you have to express $\lambda$ as rate of
entry per *year.*

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Here is what I got based on it (please let me know if you think this is incorrect): we could find $L = $ total enrollment/5 $= 16800$. Now, $\lambda$ for the new students could be computed as average number of new students per year $= 4006$ Thus, $W = W_1+W_2 = 4 + \frac{16800}{4006} = 4+4.1937 = 8.1937$ ($W_1 =$ average time-length of ALL students who graduate from the university, $W_2 =$ average time-length of ALL 1st-year students and transfer students over the 5-year period). However, this calculation results in double-count between $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Comment: The double-count occurs for all the 1st-year student who ended up graduating. So I guess $W_2$ is defined ONLY over the transfer students, so it should be equal to $\frac{16800}{2188}$? But again, this is greater than $4$, which is intuitively wrong since a student who drop out should, on average, spend less than $4$ years in a university??

Comment: I'm not sure what assumptions the author of the problem has in mind, but I think you need to focus on $λ$ as _arrival rate per year._ If many students are part-time, they will take more than 4 years to finish.

Comment: I thought that's what I tried to do in the solution above?? By saying $\lambda = $ arrival rate per year, did you mean I should calculate each  of $\lambda_{i}$ for $i=1,2,...,5$, and from $L_i = \lambda_{i}W_i$, I could calculate $W_i$. But this $W_i$ is the average time-length of students enrolled in college in year $i$, not the entire  average time-length that a student is enrolled at the university, so it's not the right way I think?? Also, could you help point out to me where my mistake was in the solution above? Your explanation on the part-time makes so much sense:)

Comment: I was not saying you are wrong, merely trying to eliminate distractions by focusing on the main point. (And to mention part-time students.) But, without context from the text, I'm honestly not sure _exactly_ what you are expected to do.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply. The problem is stated as it is, but I have another question: regards to my W_1 above, it might be less than $4$ (some students took only $3$ years to graduate, or even $2$). So I guess because the problem said *estimate*, I would assume all students who graduate take $4$ years, which is a reasonable assumption I think. So I got $W_2$ correctly, didn't I?

Comment: could you please confirm if my thought above is correct? I meant, the argument I used to arrive at the answer of $8.1937$.